# Is there a command to go to a remote server and traverse through a path and get the file names

Tags: perl, cmd, windows-server-2008, wmic

I am writing a perl script to get a filename present in a directory in a remote server , i couldn't find any WMIC command to traverse through directory ,is there  any other command to access a remote server and traverse in a specific path to find a file and retrieve the file name.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Basename qw(basename);
my $path = "\\\\vmw2160\\dir1"; 

my @full_pathes = File::Find::Rule->file->name('data.html')->in($path);print ".";
my @files = map { lc basename $_ } @full_pathes;
print foreach(@files);

my %file = map { $_ => 1 } @files;
print foreach(%file);
```

Comment: ok, it is a bit unclear. How is the remote server accessed? UNC? Mapped drive?

Comment: also, if you are searching for a specific file name, why do you want to retrieve the name if you already know it? Do you want to check if it exists and print the path to it or what is the purpose.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard : I normally used the wmic / node serverName command to narrow down to a particular server  and i want to dynamically check if  the file exists

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) module from CPAN with [Number::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/Number-Compare-0.03/lib/Number/Compare.pm) being a dependency. see comments next to some parts of the script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Basename qw(basename);

my $path = "\\\\devicename\\sharename";                  #Enter your path here, i.e Network drive
my $report = 'notfound.txt';        #This is just a log to tell you which files you searched for does not exist on the drive

print 'Enter file that contains list of files to search: ';
my $expected = <STDIN>;
   chomp $expected;
   open(my $fh, '<', $expected) or die "Could not open '$expected' $!\n";
   open(my $out, '>', $report) or die "Could not open '$report' $!\n";

my @full_pathes = File::Find::Rule->file->name('*')->in($path);
my @files = map { lc basename $_ } @full_pathes;
my %file = map { $_ => 1 } @files;

while (my $name = <$fh>) {
    chomp $name;
    if ($file{lc $name}) {  
        print "$name found\n";
    } else {
        print $out "$name\n";
    }
}
close $out;
close $fh;
```

Then create a file with a list of files you want to search for. Let's call it `myfiles.txt` and enter the files in list form:

```
filename1.txt
filename2.pdf
filename3.bat
```

then Run the script and upon request, enter the filename `myfiles.txt` to the prompt and enter.

**EDIT** modified the code to take UNC paths.

Comment: Can the code be narrowed down to particular server ,for instance can i give the server name as an argument, i am really sorry for posting a vague question

Comment: Yes, but then you would need to build in the code. I answered the answer to the specific question, if you need anything additionally, then please create a new question

Comment: how can i tweak the code to make it work for a UNC path and will the find file method find folders present in sub directories from the path.

Comment: The command runs forever , it is not stopping ,its not returning anything

Comment: have you enabled strict and warnings? is it giving you any errors? Mine works 100%

Comment: in the UNC path the share name is it same as any directory name in the server

Comment: I have taken a part of the code and placed along the description field, i have specified the unc path and i am finding a file named data.html which is in a d: drive ,how can get its unc path ,i just need to find if it exists

Comment: `\\\\servername\\d\` I assume.  How do you currently access it?

Comment: does the @files contain the file names

Comment: I don't think the path can be a unc file path